# Parsing string to local date doesn't use desired century

Tags: java, date, java-time, 2-digit-year

I am using this DateTimeFormatter:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMYY")
```

I want to parse the string `150790` and I got this error:

```
Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=15, MonthOfYear=7, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2090},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Obviously, I want to get the following `TemporalAccessor`:

```
{DayOfMonth=15, MonthOfYear=7, WeekBasedYear=1990}
```

Do you know why I got the year 2090 instead of 1990?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since this question is really about new `java.time`-package and NOT `SimpleDateFormat` I will cite following [relevant section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Year: The count of letters determines the minimum field width below
>   which padding is used. If the count of letters is two, then a reduced
>   two digit form is used. For printing, this outputs the rightmost two
>   digits. For parsing, this will parse using the base value of 2000,
>   resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive.

We see that Java-8 uses the range **2000-2099 per default**, not like `SimpleDateFormat` the range -80 years until +20 years relative to today.

If you want to configure it then you have to use [appendValueReduced()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValueReduced-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-int-). This is designed in an inconvenient way, but possible, see here:

```
String s = "150790";

// old code with base range 2000-2099
DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = 
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("ddMMyy").toFormatter();
System.out.println(dtf1.parse(s)); // 2090-07-15

// improved code with base range 1935-2034
DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = 
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("ddMM")
  .appendValueReduced(
    ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, Year.now().getValue() - 80
  ).toFormatter();
System.out.println(dtf2.parse(s)); // 1990-07-15
```

By the way, if you really want week-based years then you have to use Y instead of y or the appropriate field `IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR`. Regarding the fact that you don't have any other week-related fields I would assume the normal calendar year, not the week-based one.