# How to parse 2-digit years in Java 8 / JSR 310 / threeten.org backport?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, 2-digit-year

This question relates to parsing 2-digit years in Java 8 / JSR 310 / threeten.org backport. 2-digit years are an unfortunate fact-of-life that need to be dealt with.

I am only concerned about the ISO calendar. 
JSR 310 by default assumes a "base year" of 2000 for 2 digit years.

I see that control over the base year is accessible via

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValueReduced(...)
```

Format patterns provide a convenient mechanism for specifying date formats

```
dd-MMM-yy
M/d/yy
d/M/yy
```

I do not see a mechanism to apply a "base year" for 2-digit years after the format pattern has been applied.

Joda-time had `DateTimeFormatter.withPivotYear(int pivotYear)` as a mechanism to address this problem.

- In JSR 310, is there a mechanism to apply a base for 2-digit year after specifying a pattern?
- What is the *best-practice* recommendation for parsing 2-digit years where the base year may not be 2000?

Comment: See my answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490893/parsing-string-to-local-date-doesnt-use-desired-century). There is no convenient way to configure the pivot year (also no pattern-based way), but in my answer I have at least demonstrated a way to do so.

Comment: Meno,
Your demonstration of how to combine .appendPattern() & .appendValueReduced() is very helpful. Thank you.