# Parsing 2-digit years: Setting the pivot date with an unknown date pattern

Tags: java, date, java-time

The user will input dates in different patterns to my application. For 2-digit years, he must also determine the pivot date.

---

**Example:**
pattern = *yy-MM-dd*
pivot date = *70* (I add the current millennium and the last century for more dynamics programmatically => *1970*)

*69-04-22* becomes *2069-04-22*
*70-04-22* becomes *1970-04-22*

---

Like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29496149/3318377) it's easy to build a `DateTimeFormatter` when the date pattern (here *ddMMyy*) is known.
But since the user inputs the pattern, I'm not sure how to build the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` properly. I can't hard code it.

Do I have to parse the pattern by myself and call `appendPattern()` and `appendValueReduced()` in the right order? Or is there a built-in solution?

Comment: Not sure where your problem is. Suppose you didn't have the base date issue, and the user just entered the pattern. Do you know what you would have done then? Or is your problem that you don't trust the user to enter a proper pattern? If his pattern is valid, what's the problem with adding the `appendValueReduced` to it?

Comment: Let's suppose the pattern entered is valid. The problem is that `java.time` takes the current century (2000) when converting a 2-digit year into 4 digits. But I want to let the user decide at what year the last century (1900) or the current century (2000) is chosen.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't understand what the problem is with the given answer. What's wrong with `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(userPattern).appendValueReduced(...)`?

Comment: It won't work, because for my pattern it must be `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValueReduced(...).appendPattern(userPattern)`. So they must be called in another order and the `userPattern` has to be edited to be *-MM-dd*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the Java-8-solution (it rather looks like a hack):

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yy 'US'"; // user-input
String text = "10/04/69 US"; // user-input
Locale locale = Locale.US; // user-input, too?

int yy = pattern.indexOf("yy");
DateTimeFormatter dtf;

if (
    (yy != -1) // explanation: condition ensures exactly two letters y
    && ((yy + 2 >= pattern.length()) || pattern.charAt(yy + 2) != 'y')
) {
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
    String part1 = pattern.substring(0, yy);
    if (!part1.isEmpty()) {
        builder.appendPattern(part1);
    }
    builder.appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, 1970);
    String part2 = pattern.substring(yy + 2);
    if (!part2.isEmpty()) {
        builder.appendPattern(part2);
    }
    dtf = builder.toFormatter(locale);
} else {
    dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale);
}

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(text, dtf);
System.out.println("user-date: " + ld); // 2069-10-04
```

There is only one tiny caveat: If any user gets the crazy idea to define two times separately "yy" in the pattern then the proposed solution will fail. The correct solution would then require some kind of iterating over the pattern chars but I think that is overkill, so I leave it out here.

Just for comparison, using my external library Time4J enables following short solution because its parse engine also has the concept of setting any suitable format attributes:

```
LocalDate ld = 
  ChronoFormatter.ofDatePattern(pattern, PatternType.CLDR, locale)
  .with(Attributes.PIVOT_YEAR, 2070).parse(text).toTemporalAccessor();
```

Comment: Because you've written Time4J, I think you would be aware of a possible built-in solution. So it seems your answer is (at the moment) the only and best. Thanks!

Comment: @halloei Thanks, If someone dares to write a new time library like me - with the goal to improve or introduce a lot of features - then he must know and study very well the strengths and weaknesses of existing standards (like the new java.time-lib). If you look at the with()-methods in `DateTimeFormatter` and non-append()-methods in the builder class (like `parseCaseInsensitive()`) then you can easily see that there is no built-in-solution for your problem.