# Parse a two-digit year as 1900s rather than 2000s in java.time?

Tags: java, parsing, java-time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later parses two-digit year strings as being in the 2000s. So `90` becomes `2090`.

From the [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class documentation:

> If the count of letters is two… will parse using the base value of 2000, resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive.

I have data where values such as `90` meant `1990`.

**How can I change the pivot year for parsing two-digit year strings** to `1900` rather than `2000`?

Even better, how can I set any arbitrary pivot year, as I know some data sources have rules for partial century. For example, “If under `80`, assume 2000s, otherwise assume 1900s”.

Yes, I know, using two-digit year values is dopey. But the data was not under my control.

Comment: I think I would parse as normal, then if the year was > 2079, subtract 100 from the year.

Comment: What about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29496149/1743880 (maybe this one also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32783553/1743880).

Comment: I never understood why people were lazy to save the other 2 digits for the year, but since the Y2K problem 16 years passed!!! How come there's still living code like that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the API to get a value in the 2000-2099 range and use some conditionals to do the rest of the work. Don't worry about trying to change the API itself.

Comment: Actually, java.time does support overriding this assumption of 2000s. You can easily set your own pivot year. See [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32505814/642706).