# how to convert a String date value of pattern dd-MMM-yy to Date object of Pattern dd/MM/yyyy in java

Tags: java, spring, date

I have

```
String dateAsString = "15-May-84";
```

and I want to convert it as

```
Date date = 15/05/1984;
```

first try

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(dateAsString )), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

second try

```
LocalDate.parse(dateAsString , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")));
```

I tried many ways with `SimpleDateFormat` and `LocalDate` but it's always returning 15/05/0084.

can anyone help here please

Comment: can you show us what you tried please?

Comment: tried below codes:  LocalDate.parse("15-May-84", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")))       and                                          new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(15-May-84)), "dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: edit your question and put the code

Comment: In short, use a LocalDate class and two DateFormatter instances for parsing the old date and formatting the new one. Also, this is a very googleable question that probably has numerous answers on SO. Next time, please search bit harder.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) are the classes to use.

Comment: Thnaks Jilles, bit it's returning 15/05/0094 while passing 15-May-94 with the edited code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing string to local date doesn't use desired century](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490893/parsing-string-to-local-date-doesnt-use-desired-century)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's not good to use year as two digits as a string, Why?

### Explanation

to parse your date, it is easy, you can use:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy")
        .withLocale(Locale.US);

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("15-May-84", formatter);
```

### But

This will return `2084-05-15`, which I think you are not looking to this, but you look to `1984-05-15`.

### Quick Fix

So to solve this, you can use use `minusYears(100)`:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("15-May-84", formatter).minusYears(100);
```

### But

Which can be a problem to other years like `15-May-20` which will return `1920-05-15`.

> For that I don't advice at all to use two digits in your year as a
>   string.

### Unless

unless you have another confirmation that your date is between `1900` and `1999`, or between `2000` and `2999`. in this case you can create a (safe) custom parser!

---

#### Important

Don't use the legacy Date library, instead use only the modern `java.time` API

Comment: Instead of using minusYears, it’s better to build a DateFormatter with an explicit base year, using [appendValueReduced](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValueReduced%28java.time.temporal.TemporalField,int,int,int%29).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I am showing you the modern way using `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` beacase java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is so nice to work with. The classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are not only poorly designed, they are also long outdated, so I don’t recommend trying those.

I am assuming that you want a date that is *today or in the past*, not in the future and less than 100 years ago.

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    int thisYear = today.getYear();

    String dateAsString = "15-May-84";

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("d-MMM-")
            .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 2, thisYear - 99)
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, dateFormatter);
    if (date.isAfter(today)) {
        // Go 100 years back
        dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("d-MMM-")
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 2, thisYear - 100)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        date = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, dateFormatter);
    }

    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 1984-05-15

If you want a different base year, just supply a different base year. And if you can, do a stricter range check so you are quite sure that you get a correct date for dates near the ends of the valid range. For example, if parsing the birth date of a living person aged between 18 and 80, make that your limits.

### What went wrong in your code?

1. When using a formatter for parsing your string, you need to supply a format pattern string that specifies the format to be parsed, not the desired result format. When parsing a string with hyphens, you need hyphens in the format pattern string, not slashes. And BTW, you cannot have a `LocalDate` or `Date` in your desired a format. Neither a `LocalDate` nor a `Date` has a format. You can have a format only in a `String`.
2. Using `yyyy` with `SimpleDateFormat` specifies that the date string contains a full year, so year 84 is taken as year 84 CE, 1936 years ago. `uuuu` with `DateTimeFormatter` is even stricter, it specifies that the year must be at least 4 digits, so cannot parse `84` at all.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to work with different date formats

```
    String dateAsString = "15-May-84";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy");
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = format.parse(dateAsString);
    String newDateString = newFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(newDateString);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat#parse`:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("26/06/2020");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It does not even make use of the `dateAsString` value.