# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23 de marzo de 2021"

Tags: java, spring

I have a date that comes to me as a string type as follows:

```
String fecha = "23 de marzo de 2021";
```

But I want to change the date as follows:

```
String resultado = "23-03-2021";
```

I tried using the following but can't:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("23 de marzo de 2021");
    System.out.println("Fecha --->" + date1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: @Dharman - I've translated the three sentences into English leaving the code as it is.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I see, but we really shouldn't be translating questions. Please close them next time. I don't this question will be very useful in the future. Maybe you know of a duplicate that could be used to close this question instead?

Comment: @Dharman - There is no exact duplicate e.g. as mentioned in this comment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665987/parse-oracle-date-to-java#comment117882069_66665987, there are differences from duplicate targets which came from my searches.

Comment: Hi @DANIEL, does the translation accurately reflect your words/question? It is the asker's responsibility to post in English on Stack Overflow, not an answerer's prerogative.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the correct format which is `dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy` for your date string.
2. Always use `Locale` with date-time formatting/parsing API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        Date date1 = sdfInput.parse("23 de marzo de 2021");

        // Default string i.e. Date#toString implementation
        System.out.println(date1);

        // Custom string
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(date1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Mar 23 00:00:00 GMT 2021
23-03-2021
```

Note that the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' uuuu", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("23 de marzo de 2021", dtfInput);

        // Default string i.e. LocalDate#toString implementation
        System.out.println(date1);

        // Custom string
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        System.out.println(dtfOutput.format(date1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-23
23-03-2021
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Please do not answer non-English questions. They're off-topic on Stack Overflow and must be closed with reason "Needs clarity" or "Not suitable..."