# How to find the day when year, month and date is given?

Tags: java, calendar, date-format, localdate

I need a solution to return day (Monday,Tuesday...), when i have inputs like YEAR, MONTH, DATE.

```
public static String findDay(int month, int day, int year) { // code here }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that on this site you are required — also for your own sake — to perform a search before posting a question, and also in the question to report what you found and in what way it fell short of giving you what you wanted. Because you will often find a better answer faster that way, and because it allows us to write answers that more precisely and specifically address your issue.

Comment: Vaibhav Atray - The valuable comment by @OleV.V. will certainly help you to use SO in a better way in the future.  At the same time, going by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665987/parse-oracle-date-to-java#comment117882069_66665987), this question doesn't have any duplicate on SO (so far I haven't been able to find an exact duplicate of this question).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I didn’t find the exact same question asked before either. The skilled questioner may be able to piece an answer together from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499228/creating-java-date-object-from-year-month-day) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date), for example. That reader should prefer to skip all the answers using `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and the other old date and time classes, though, and go for the ones using java.time like your own good answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the parameters, create a `LocalDate` from which you can get the weekday.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(findDay(2021, 4, 30));
    }

    public static String findDay(int year, int month, int day) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        return date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Friday
```

Learn more about the the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>  from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>